# Microsoft office 2013 freeze (not open) after working on another app for sometime

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

I have a problem with my microsoft office (not just word, but all microsoft office products).

When i open a page, either word, excel, powerpoint .., the page working good, then if i click Alt+tab to go to another application and then go back to the microsoft office it works, but if i was in microsfot office and then clicked alt+tab to go to another application and stay in that applciation for a while (10 minutes at least), and then come back to office, the office is not working then. In other words, the office is not opening at all.

i am on windows 7

help please

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess is that you could have a computer with low memory (RAM). After a while of not using a program, Windows will release some of the memory used by that program and save that memory to disk, and it will take quite a while for Windows to reload that memory from disk when you return to that program. But if the Office program does not wake up after waiting (without touching anything) for a few minutes, something else is probably wrong.

If the problem really is lack of memory and you cannot just add more memory (RAM), [adding a fast SD card or USB stick and setting it up as a ReadyBoost device](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/readyboost) is an excellent alternative. I have tried it myself on several older computers with surprisingly good results – the computers feel at least twice as fast afterwards. It does take some hours of using the computer, though, before the ReadyBoost really kicks in, as it will have to create a good cache first.

Comment: it is not memory problem 100%, because I wait for like 20 minutes without touching the laptop and the office didn't open, plus, i have 16 GB ram, and i use maximum 3 GB, really maximum 3GB

Comment: Haha, I agree, with those specs it is definitely not a memory problem! :-) I just couldn't see that from your original post.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is that there is a problem with your Office installation.  To repair your Office installation, do the following:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Go to Programs and Features, and select Microsoft Office (or individual Office applications)
3. Select the Office application you want to repair, e.g., "Microsoft Word"
4. Right-click and choose "Change"
5. Select "Repair" and follow the prompts

More information available at [Microsoft Knowledge Base: Repair an Office Installation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)